# Limiting search suggestions to a certain number?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I believe that Magento shows up to 1000 suggestions by default (if there are that many). I would like to limit this to 5.

I came across this topic: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21155/ .. but given that it's 6 years old I'm afraid to try it on our site (which is generating a lot of revenue and cannot risk going down). I couldn't find anything else related to this that seemed reliable.

Has anyone done this before? I really wish they would make this more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `public function getSuggestData()` method within the  **Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php** file with the following:

Change (Around line 71):

```
$collection = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestCollection();
```

To:

```
$collection = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestCollection()->setPageSize(5);
```

The difference is just appending the `setPageSize(5)` function to the selection, where the `5` is the limit of results to be returned.

To make this change, be sure to override the block the correct way by using an extension, or copying the file to the **app/core/local/Mage** folder.

More on rewriting Magento Blocks: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

TIL that Max Chadwick developped a free module that implements search autocomplete limit as well as other catalog search autocomplete improvements. You can find it here: https://github.com/mpchadwick/Mpchadwick_SearchAutocompleteConfigmarator/